# Pass a parameter into function called in template

Tags: angularjs

Here is my angular code:

```
   'use strict';

var app=angular.module('app',['ngRoute','appFactories']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/admin', {
            templateUrl: '/pages/admin/allcards.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })}]);

var factories=angular.module('appFactories',['ngResource']);
factories
    .factory('CardFactory',['$resource',
        function($resource) {
            return{
                all: $resource('/worldonlinenew/card/common', {}, {query: {method: 'GET', params: {id: '@id'}}}),
            }
        }])
    .factory('StaticFactory',['$resource',
        function($resource) {
            return{
                languages: $resource('/worldonlinenew/static/languages', {}, {query: {method: 'GET',isArray: true}}),
            }
        }]);

app.controller('CardController',function CardController($scope, CardFactory, StaticFactory){
    $scope.card=null;
    $scope.languages=null;

    $scope.translate=function(language, text){
        for(var i=0;i<text.translatedTexts.length;i++){
            if(text.translatedTexts[i].language==language){
                return translate;
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.initCard = function(id){
        $scope.card=CardFactory.all.query({id: id});
        $scope.languages=StaticFactory.languages.query({id: id});
    }
});
```

And here is my template, where i'm trying to call this function:

```
</head>
<body ng-controller="CardController" >
<div class="container">

    <div th:attr="ng-init='initCard(\''+${id}+'\');'"></div>
    <h4 sec:authentication="name"></h4>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <h1>Card ID: {{card.id}}</h1>
        <!-- Next two strings works fine -->
        <h1>name one: {{card.name.translatedTexts[0].content}}</h1>
        <h1>name two: {{card.name.translatedTexts[1].content}}</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="language in languages" ng->
            <h1 ng-bind="translate(language,card.name)"></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My browser's console print something like "can't get `translatedTexts` of undifined, i.e. `text` parameter is undifined. But `language` parameter is ok, because it's declared in `ng-repeat`.

Comment: where is card defined? In your case it seems like card.name is undefined.

Comment: @Etse, object `card` is defined in my controller and filling from `$resource`. For example, `<h1>{{card.id}}</h1>` is work.

Comment: worked https://jsfiddle.net/x8nnfdzd/3/ check it.

Comment: but i think logic wrong. bind model in iterator is not right thing. Why bind again and again if need only one `card.name`?

Comment: @diproart `ng-model="card.name"` is mistake, i'm sorry. But look at my function, for each language function returns different objects.

Comment: Error is clear: card.name is not defined. So just fix it. Or post complete code, otherwise it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, working sample code here. If `card.name` always `undefined` it means when iterator working but var not ready on not in same scope in same time. See sample and check your code.

[Update]
Yes. Problem in `initCard` function. This function 'sync' but `$resource` native `async` (`CardFactory.all.query`,`StaticFactory.languages.query`). And you must wait when function `resolve`.

Example:

```
app.controller('CardController',function($scope,CardFactory){

   init();

   /////////
   function init(){

      CardFactory.all.query({id:1})
       .$promise
       .then(function(result){
          // ready
       });

      // or
     CardFactory.all.query({id:1}, function(cards){
       // ... if
       $scope.cards = cards;
     });

   }
})
```

- [working code here](https://jsfiddle.net/x8nnfdzd/4/)
- [angular $resource docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: After your code, i've understood, that problem is in my `init` function. This function makes get requests and fill my variables by response data. But if i remove calling of `init` function and fill variables manually, like in your code, then all works fine.

Comment: And again it doesn't work :( It seems like `ng-bind` run one time(before end of the `$resource` requests), print error, and don't run anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, here is the answer! As i've wrote, `ng-bind=translate(language,card.name)` executes before `init` function, and as we can see, in my model `$scope.card=null;`. So, field `card.name` not only empty, this field doesn't exists. 
Solution:

```
function Card(){
    this.id=new Number();
    this.name=new Text();
}

function Text(){
    this.id=new Number();
    this.name=new String();
    this.translatedTexts=new Array();
}

$scope.card=new Card();
```